# Inductive definition yields "Ignoring recursive call"

Tags: coq

I have an inductive definition which—after evaluating—prints the warning "Ignoring recursive call". It seems that the definition works perfectly fine. However, I am still curious why exactly this warning is given. Below is a minimal example.

```
Inductive testor :=
| Constr1 : list testor -> testor
| Constr2 : testor -> testor.
```

I think the culprit is `list testor` in the first constructor. On the other hand, the warning is not given without the second constructor.

**Q**: Why is the warning emitted? Does it mean a restriction is imposed on the inductive definition?

I am using Coq 8.5.

Comment: A side question: Why doesn't this have to be declared as  _Coinductive_  type?

Comment: @Cryptostasis I derived this example from a definition of a small programming language. I have never worked with coinductive types, but from what I understand, those are used when dealing with infinite objects. Usually, programs are finite. What is the advantage of declaring such definition as coinductive?

Comment: That was a wrong assumption. I thought _testor_ would be a non terminating type. Now I see that testor is indeed terminating as _Constr1 nil_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `testor` is called a *nested inductive type* because of the occurrence of `list testor`. There is no restriction, you can safely use the definition, it's just the autogenerated induction principle is not very useful. This [Coq-club thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.science.mathematics.logic.coq.club/4609) deals with this issue. Here is an excerpt from Adam Chlipala's answer:

> The warning is just about the heuristic attempts to generate a useful 
>   induction principle.  Nested inductive types (like your [AllList] use 
>   here) call for some cleverness to build the right inductive case schemas.

For more details, see the "Nested Inductive Types" section in [this chapter](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Cpdt.InductiveTypes.html) of CPDT.